# Netflix conductor - Trigger workflow on kafka event

Tags: microservices, netflix-conductor

I am looking for a good example on how to start the execution of a workflow in Netflix conductor by subscribing to a Kafka topic. I have tried reading through the conductor documentation however I am unclear on how this could you be implemented. Can someone please help me with this?